# How to show line numbers only at fixed intervals?

Tags: line-numbers

I know how to show absolute as well as cursor-relative line numbers but I do not need to see each line number and they look too crowded. I would like to just see line numbers at an interval, say every 5 lines eg. 5, 10, 15, and so on. Is there a way to achieve this in vim?

Comment: I don't think this is possible without hacking vim c source.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show only every n relative line number](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4288/show-only-every-n-relative-line-number)

Comment: It is not working for me. Seeing errors. ```Error detected while processing function Refresh..AddLine```

Comment: You can use my [DynamicSigns](https://github.com/chrisbra/DynamicSigns) Vim plugin

Answer (score 2):

For Neovim, there is a [line-number-interval.nvim](https://github.com/IMOKURI/line-number-interval.nvim) plugin that can provide the functionality. Screenshot below demonstrates the default look of the plugin (which is on par with what vscode can do), after following commands. Just note that the screenshots on Github repo are outdated.

```
:set number
:LineNumberIntervalEnable
```

[image: Neovim line-number-interval plugin]