# Know where there is no more space on pandoc beamer presentation

Tags: neovim, filetype-markdown, ruler

I write my presentations in Markdown, and use pandoc to compile into a PDF with latex's beamer.

An issue I frequently encounter is that I write too much, and so the content gets out of the slide.

Here is an example:

```
# Example

## Example

I'm writing too much.

I really write too much.

$E=mc^2$

$F=ma$

$V=RI$

This is the equation for voltage.

Voltage is measures in Volts.

Resistance is measured in ohms ($\omega$).

Current is measured in amperes.

The previous one was an equation from physics.

It ties force with mass and acceleration. The equation before that was Einstein's.
```

Which results in:

[image]

As you can see, "was Einstein's" is out of the slide.

How can I have an horizontal ruler that tells me when there is  no more space on the slide?

I'm using neovim.

Comment: Offtopic: the symbol for Ohm is a capital omega Ω. Lowercase omega ω is commonly used for angular frequency in AC circuits (or angular velocity in general).

Comment: I am really wondering how should Vim know, whether this will fit on a slide on a totally different medium

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt a horizontal ruler placed on the 25th line after the line that starts with "##" would be good enough for me, if there is no other way.

Comment: FWIW, LaTeX doesn't even know how much fits on one slide and happily produces output beyond the page. What about the old rule of thumb to have no more than three bullet points per slide? Efficient use of slide real estate rarely makes for a good presentation.

Comment: @robertspierre "a horizontal ruler"? what is that supposed to be?

Comment: a horizontal box, a horizontal stripe

Comment: in an *editor* ?

Comment: yes in an editor. LIke github.com/Bekaboo/deadcolumn.nvim but horizontally instead of vertically

Comment: That is just a fancy colorcolumn. I am pretty sure you could script something, using signs, e.g. like this answer here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/4317/71 but nothing out of the box. And this goes way beyond what an editor should do.

Answer (score 0):

You can highlight the a specific line (line 25 in this example) of your text with the following calls:

```
hi LightBlue guibg=#00afff ctermbg=039
match LightBlue /\%25l.*/
```

Of course this is a very rough way. The limit in the number of lines will depend of the type of line (normal, list items, title, subtitle) but also on the symbol that you are using (e.g. mathematical formula).

I would personally use the [markdown-preview](https://github.com/iamcco/markdown-preview.nvim) plugin to have a visual hint of how my slides looks to avoid making them too long.

[image]

Comment: I have markdown-preview plugin, but it does not generate beamer slides, it generates a continuous HTML, no? How do I know where the slide would end?

Comment: Also, I would need that horizontal line to move for a new slide